# pipコマンドからの警告(to use a virtual environment)の対処方法

Tags: python, pip

JupyterLab上で、BeautifulSoapを利用するために、以下のpip3コマンドを実行したところ、

```
!pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

次のような警告メッセージが表示されました。

```
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

virtual environmentを利用するよう勧められているようなのですが、具体的には何をすればよいのでしょうか？
（virtual environmentとは何のことでしょうか？）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この辺の記事 [Python3系のアップロード　pip installをするとRunning pip as root will break packages and permissions.](https://teratail.com/questions/358301), [「WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.」について](https://kamatimaru.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/05/22/041527), [CentOS8にpython3とopencvをインストール](https://paso.iroiro.jp/item/248.html) を参考に使っているOSや動作させている環境・IDEなどの出来る限り詳細な情報を追記してみてください。実際には気にしなくて良いのかもしれません。

Comment: 「virtual environmentとは何のことでしょうか？」という部分についてのコメントですが，そのエラーメッセージに載っている URL を辿ると出てくるように [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/venv.html) のことを指していると思います．これは “仮想環境” を作成するための Python の標準モジュールで（したがって `pip` で何かを追加インストールすることなく使用できます）Python パッケージを特定のディレクトリ以下にすべてインストールすることで，同一の PC 内で複数の環境を共存させるといったようなことを実現するのに役立ちます．ただし @kunif さんも指摘されているように，今回ケースについては venv を使うことで何かメリットがあるかどうかというと何とも言えないような気もします（その警告は必ずしも妥当でない場合にも表示されることがあるようです）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

使用している OSが何かが問題で

例えばシステム内の Pythonを置き換えてしまうと, ある種の OSでは動作に支障をきたします
OS側で提供してる各種コマンドの一部に Python製があり, バージョンが変わると動作が変化する あるいは動作しない可能性が出てくるため

それは Pythonパッケージも同じで, 同名のパッケージあるいは「あるパッケージが存在すればそれを使う」ようなパターンなど, いつの間にか各種ツールの動作がおかしくなってた, などがあり得る

その手の心配がない(最初から Python入ってなかったなど)場合は無視してよいし
OSと Pythonが密接している環境では, システム側とユーザー側で環境切り分けるなど対処する方法があります

仮に問題がなくとも, 仮想環境があればいくつかの環境を切り替えて使う・別のバージョンのパッケージを利用するなど利点は多々あるので, 仮想環境利用してみるのもよいでしょう

- (docs.python.org) [venv --- 仮想環境の作成](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/venv.html)
  それまでは virtualenv と呼ばれていたツール。現在は標準機能。
- [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/)
  科学計算（データサイエンス、機械学習アプリケーション、大規模データ処理、予測分析など）のためのPythonおよびR言語の無料のオープンソースディストリビューション
  [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Pythonディストリビューション)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3)) より
- pipenv, poetry
  次世代の仮想環境
- [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)
  Python Version Management

---

Anacondaはそれ自体で完結しているため 他のを使う必要はない。他のを混ぜると環境が壊れることも

- 各種 Pythonパッケージには, Anaconda, venv, pipenv, poetry など
- Python自体のバージョン管理には, Anacondaか, pyenv

##### pip について

pip については, Anaconda利用するなら pip使用禁止 (壊れて再インストールの話 それなり上る)
pipenvなど次世代仮想環境では, 通常は pipenv コマンドで行う (ので使わなくてよい)

pip コマンドを(どうしても？)使用する場合は, "user install" を利用するとよいでしょう
`--user` オプションを付けるかどうかでインストールされる場所が異なる (ことがある)(自動で付く環境も存在する)

参考: pip documentation: User Guide [User Installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs)

Answer (score 0):

venvについて、おおむね理解できました。ありがとうございます。
[Python3系のアップロード　pip installをするとRunning pip as root will break packages and permissions.](https://teratail.com/questions/358301)の、３つの条件に当てはまらないから、警告が発生したと理解できました。今回はDockerを利用しているので、この警告は無視できると判断しまた。

ちなみに、WSL Dockerコンテナ内のUbuntu 20.04.4 LTSの、
Python 3.8.10
pip 22.0.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
を利用していました。root権限で実行されていました。
（コメント欄は改行できないため、ここに記載します。）